# Free/Open Source Text File Editing Software Capable Of Reading Massive Files?

Tags: text, open-source, editor

I have used UtraEdit in the past, but was not entirely impressed for the price of $60 when the only aspect of it I enjoyed (over notepad++) was it's large file adaptability.

What free programs are good at reading/editing massive text files?

Comment: The first two that come to mind are vim and emacs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use vim so I recommend it. It can perfectly handle big files.

However if you want to edit big files sequentially the most powerful way to do it is by using a programming language which has an input/output capability: python, perl, C, Golang and many many others.

For python see this answer: [Lazy Method for Reading Big File in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python)

For editing you might consider regular expressions.

Comment: Vim took a second or two to load, but worked even better than UltraEdit imho in terms of scrolling through a massive text file. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

And (at least on Linux) if you just want to just *look* into the huge files, not *change* them, you could also use **pagers** like the `more`,  `less`,  `most` commands.

If you can modify the application handling these files, you should make it able to construct a huge content out of smaller files. A simple trick might be that if a "file name" starts with some special character like eg `!` or `|` you use `popen`& `pclose` instead of `fopen` & `fclose` , that is something like

```
FILE* input;
bool ispipe;
char* filename;
//... get the filename; open the file or pipe
if (filename[0] == '!') {
  input = popen(filename+1, "r");
  ispipe = true;
}
else {
  input = fopen(filename, "r");
  ispipe = false;
}
//... process the input using sequential I/O ...
// close input:
if (ispipe) 
   fclose(file);
else
   pclose(file);
```

Then you might pass `'!cat foo1 foo2 foo3'` as the program argument giving `filename`.

And you did not define what you call a huge file: on a common Linux desktop with x86-64 processor (and 64 bits linux) and 8 gigabytes of RAM, you can edit a 4Gb file with standard editors (but I recommend avoiding that situation).